# Openshift RoR. Cant connect to db through mysql.sock

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, openshift

I have Openshift RoR app. When I trying to run some rake task which uses DB, it gives me error:

```
rake aborted!
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

When I pushed my app 1st time there was no socket value in database.yml, I added it later trying to fix this issue, set it to env variable of socket, which is: 
"/var/lib/openshift/*some_key*/mysql//socket/mysql.sock
" In mysql.log I have this same socket too. So I don't understand where is this "/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock" came from. I guess I need rebuild my app somehow, but it only restarts on "push" now. Or is this wrong idea?

EDIT: Here is my database.yml from .openshift/config. As i mentioned i added "soket: <%=ENV['OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_SOCKET']%>" later, after first push. I just tried 'force_clean_build' marker, it didn't help though.

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: database
  username: root
  password: psswd
  host: localhost
test:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: database
  username: root
  password: psswd
  host: localhost
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: "<%=ENV['OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME']%>"
  username: "<%=ENV['OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME']%>"
  password: "<%=ENV['OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD']%>"
  host:     <%=ENV['OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST']%>
  port:     <%=ENV['OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT']%>
  soket:    <%=ENV['OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_SOCKET']%>
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of your database.yml file? (remove any usernames & Passwords

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out server didn't run all necessary rake:db tasks on deploy. That's why I was getting 'We are sorry...' error. And to run rake tasks through ssh, You need to add "RAILS_ENV=production" before it, like this:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake db:setup
```

This 2 problems (not necessarily connected) made it look for me, like there is problem with DB config.